# Can I store template parameter of a constructor inside the class

Tags: c++, templates

the class is not a template, only the constructor is, for example:

```
struct S{
   template<typename LAMBDA>
   S(LAMBDA lambda_obj){...};

   void f(){
      //I want to use lambda_obj here,
      //but dont know how to do it
   }
};
```

Is there any way that I can store lambda_obj inside the struct, and then use it later in f()?
I cannot make S a template. It would be much easier if I can.
I met the problem in a test, and I think it is quite interesting.

Thank you for answering!

Comment: You can use `std::function`. It is a good way to store lambdas as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the signature of the callable type that S will be constructed with then you can store the argument passed to the constructor in an std::function as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct S {

    std::function<void(void)> func;

    template<typename LAMBDA>
    S(LAMBDA lambda_obj) {
        func = lambda_obj;
    };

    void f() {
        func();
    }
};

void DoSomething()
{
    std::cout << "foobar\n";
}

int main()
{
    S s(DoSomething);
    s.f();
}
```

If you do not know the signature, you could do it with variadic templates and type erasure -- basically you can do it the way that std::function is itself implemented, although in that case, the member function f would have to be a function template as well as the constructor.

Comment: Thank you so much. I would do some research on it!

Answer (score 0):

**No**. Without making the `template class S`, you cannot store `lambda_obj`.

However, often making the constructor alone a template is not required, especially in this scenario. From the name, I presume that you might be passing a lambda function. If it has a similar signature, then receive it as below:

```
struct S {
  std::function<void(int)> m_lambda;  // `void(int)` only for demo; can be any type
  S (std::function<void(int)> lambda_obj) : m_lambda(lambda_obj) {}
  void f () { m_lambda(3); }
};
```